# Dynamic BASE_HREF in Angular

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, traefik

So, using Angular 14 and I want to serve application on a given path, that may be different depending on environment. These environments are not known in advance, so updating angular.json with additional configuration is not an option, as well as using --base-href option during build phase.

To mitigate this, I am using envsubst to read docker's environment variables and inject them into app configuration (javascript file that loads given values into window object) on container creation. Then, I use this value to provide base href via the injection token APP_BASE_HREF.

Angular app is deployed in docker container with `ngingx` image and Traefik is used to route traffic to it.

However, this configuration only works for first level of path. For example, with this configuration, paths like `/` and `/profile` work ok, however, when I try to directly load path `/admin/panel`, the `/admin` part gets added to base href and tries to look for scripts at `/basepath/admin`, altough `admin` is not part of base path. Also, assets are not working properly as well.

My question is, what is the proper Angular 14 way of preparing application to work on any base href given?

My minimal code for this problem:

src/assets/environment.template.js:

```
(function (window) {
    window["env"] = window["env"] || {};
    
    window["environment"]["appBase"] = "$APPBASE";
})(this);
```

src/index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <script src="assets/environment.js"></script>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

src/enviroment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  appBase: window["environment"]["appBase"]
}
```

src/app/app.module.ts:

```
export function AppBaseHrefFactory(): string {
    return environment.appBase;
}

...
providers: [
  { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: AppBaseHrefFactory },
],
...
```

entrypoint.sh (docker container entrypoint):

```
#!/bin/sh

envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/apps/my-app/assets/environment.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/apps/my-app/assets/environment.js

exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `--base-href` option while building in the Docker?

Comment: I am not building project in docker. The application is built in CI pipeline and then packaged into docker image.